# Rewrite source of incoming packets to 127.0.0.1 with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, docker

Let's consider a server running MySQL server, listening on 127.0.0.1:3306.

I would now like to give Docker containers running on the same host access to the MySQL server. MySQL would reject incoming connections, since they don't originate from 127.0.0.1, but from the container's IP. I could change the binding address of MySQL to '*', but then I would rely entirely on the firewall to prevent access from other networks. Therefore, I would prefer to keep MySQL listening on 127.0.0.1, and use iptables to "white list" the containers. I am not an iptables expert, so I just tried different combinations, using -t nat INPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING, but couldn't get it to work so far. I also set "net.ipv4.conf.docker0.route_localnet" to 1, since that looks necessary.

How can I make iptables set the source address to 127.0.0.1 for all packets coming on the docker0 interface (or a specific IP or network), and handle the following address translation?

Comment: If you NAT the source address to the loopback address, you could never send a reply back to a request because anything sent to the loopback address for a reply will loop right back into the server. Loopback addresses, by definition, are not allowed to be routed.

Comment: @RonMaupin isn't that the point of the route_localnet option? "route_localnet - BOOLEAN Do not consider loopback addresses as martian source or destination while routing. This enables the use of 127/8 for local routing purposes. default FALSE"

Comment: Can someone tell me why my question is downvoted?

Comment: Then that doesn't follow RFC 6890, which says that anything in the `127.0.0.0/8` range is not forwardable.

Comment: I don't know the specific reasons that anyone voted your question down, but hovering over the down arrow gives you the canonical reason: "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_."

Comment: My interpretation is that the RFC's forbids 127.0.0.1 on the network. route_localnet allows routing within the kernel. I don't see any reason why a RFC would care what happens in a kernel. Even the docker containers don't see anything of this. They are communicating normally with the external IP address.

Comment: I have noticed that many things in Linux don't really follow the RFCs. It may be that Linux allows loopback addresses to be routed internally, but that could break some things in other RFCs, e.g. detecting MPLS data plane failures and BFD, which depend on those addresses to not be routable. Loopback addresses should not get sent to a routing process. Anything sent to a loopback address should immediately be sent right back into the host, bypassing the routing process.

Comment: One point here is that interfaces and IP addresses are two separate things. MySQL binds to the `lo` interface when listening to `localhost`. Even if you could use IPTables to change source address to `127.0.0.1`, it would still arrive on the VM via its external interface. VM's network subsystem most likely drops this packet, since it would arrive on a source  address outside of its IP subnet. In order to further diagnose what exactly is happening, you need to provide TCPDump captures on locahost and VM subnet interfaces on both host and guest when you try to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: I have done something similar to this with haproxy and layer 4 vips.  Not that you should, I am just saying haproxy makes what you are trying to do really easy.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen good point

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: it looks like iptables is the wrong tool for the job. I installed rinetd and configured it like this:

```
# bindadress    bindport    connectaddress  connectport
172.17.0.1      3308        127.0.0.1       3306
```

rinetd binds only to the Docker address (172.17.0.1), and forwards connection from the containers to the MySQL server running on the host. From MySQL's perspective, the connections are coming from 127.0.0.1, so it happily accepts them.

It would be much easier if MySQL would support multiple bind addresses, but since the corresponding feature request have been open for 11 years, I guess it is not going to be implemented any time soon (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14979).